# Cubic and non convex optimisation problems in portfolio optimisation

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, portfolio, cvxpy, non-convex

I have the following cost function for portfolio allocation, which considers also the skweness,

[image]

w are the weights to be found, mu is the return vector, Sigma is the covariance matrix, K is the co-skewness matrix, gamma is the risk aversion (let's say is a constant number).

This problem is not convex as far as I know and not quadratic but cubic..so how can I minimise it, in order to fall the global minimum rather that a local one?

I guess I cannot use cvxpy, what are the alternatives for such example or ingeneral for higher order moments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is convex either. That would imply you need a global MINLP solver (such as Baron, Couenne or Antigone). An alternative is to reformulate the problem as a non-convex quadratic problem (some extra variables and constraints are needed for this). This would allow you to use Gurobi.

Comment: This is an interesting point..so you say I could transform the cubic part in a constraint? Can you suggest how..in that case I guess I might stick to cvxpy class

Comment: No, it is still non-convex, but Gurobi can solve non-convex quadratic problems. I think cvxpy will refuse to generate the model (it insists on convex problems).

Comment: cool great..so can you give me a ref or a link where it is shown how to transform the cubic part into a contraint? after that I can implement the Gurobi approach. Thanks!

Comment: It is simple: if the objective has a term `x*y*z` then we can replace this by `w*z` subject to `w=x*y`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen are there any textbooks or tutorials that elaborate a bit more on the transforming cubic functions to quadratic functions trick?